# Node.js Buffer and Encoding

Tags: node.js

I have an HTTP endpoint where user uploads file. I need to read the file contents and then store it to DB. I can read it to `Buffer` and getting string from it.

The problem is, then file content is not `UTF-8` I can see "strange" symbols in output string.

Is that possible somehow to detect the encoding of `Buffer` contents and serialise it to string correctly?

Comment: Perhaps [node-icu-charset-detector](https://npmjs.org/package/node-icu-charset-detector)?

Comment: looked to that, but does not suite me well, because of additional dependecies..

Comment: Is it possible to store the file as-is like a binary ? If the user does not care/ask about encoding why store it in particular encoding.

Comment: Just need to display the content of file after..